# Unable to see the updated state -React with refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate, refs

I am unable to view the updated state with mouse moves when using setState() post mounting. What is wrong with the below approach? The state is not updated post mounting the RefDemo Component .
The requirementis to have a slider with 3 thumbs which should all start from 0 and can be dragged individually to different positions.
[image: One slider with 3 pointers]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Slider.css";

class RefsDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.slider1 = React.createRef();
    this.slider2 = React.createRef();
    this.slider3 = React.createRef();
    this.value1 = React.createRef();
    this.value2 = React.createRef();
    this.value3 = React.createRef();
    this.bar = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      lastOffset1: 0,
      posCurrentX1: 0,
      lastOffset2: 0,
      posCurrentX2: 0,
      lastOffset3: 0,
      posCurrentX3: 0,
      name: ""
    };

    this.range = 100;
    //console.log(this.state);
    this.onmouseDown1 = this.onmouseDown1.bind(this);
    this.onmouseDown2 = this.onmouseDown2.bind(this);
    this.onmouseDown3 = this.onmouseDown3.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(this.slider1);
    //var {lastOffset1, posCurrentX1, lastOffset2, posCurrentX2, lastOffset3, posCurrentX3} = this.state
    this.barLength = getComputedStyle(this.bar.current).width;
    this.sliderLength = getComputedStyle(this.slider1.current).width;
    this.travelLength = Math.round(
      this.barLength.substring(0, this.barLength.length - 2)
    );
    console.log(this.state);
    this.slider1.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown1);

    this.slider2.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown2);
    this.slider3.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown3);
  }
  onType = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      name: event.target.value
    });
  };

  onmouseDown1 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const posInitialX = event.clientX;

    this.slider1.current.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
      this.slider1.current.onMouseMove = null;
      this.slider1.current.onMouseUp = null;
      //this.lastOffset1 = this.posCurrentX1;

      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        lastOffset1: this.state.posCurrentX1
      });
    });

    this.slider1.current.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      //this.posCurrentX1 = this.lastOffset1 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        posCurrentX1: this.state.lastOffset1 + event.clientX - posInitialX
      });

      //console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);

      if (
        this.state.posCurrentX1 <= this.travelLength &&
        this.state.posCurrentX1 >= 0
      ) {
        //   console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider1.current.style.left = `${this.state.posCurrentX1}px`;
        this.value1.current.innerHTML = Math.round(
          (this.range / this.travelLength) * this.state.posCurrentX1
        );
      }
    });
  };
  onmouseDown2 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const posInitialX = event.clientX;

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
      this.slider2.current.onMouseMove = null;
      this.slider2.current.onMouseUp = null;
      //this.lastOffset2 = this.posCurrentX2;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        lastOffset2: this.state.posCurrentX2
      });
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      //this.posCurrentX2 = this.lastOffset2 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        posCurrentX2: this.state.lastOffset2 + event.clientX - posInitialX
      });

      // console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);

      if (
        this.state.posCurrentX2 <= this.travelLength &&
        this.state.posCurrentX2 >= 0
      ) {
        // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider2.current.style.left = `${this.state.posCurrentX2}px`;
        this.value2.current.innerHTML = Math.round(
          (this.range / this.travelLength) * this.state.posCurrentX2
        );
      }
    });
  };
  onmouseDown3 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const posInitialX = event.clientX;

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
      this.slider3.current.onMouseMove = null;
      this.slider3.current.onMouseUp = null;
      //this.lastOffset3 = this.posCurrentX3;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        lastOffset3: this.state.posCurrentX3
      });
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      //this.posCurrentX3 = this.lastOffset3 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        posCurrentX3: this.state.lastOffset3 + event.clientX - posInitialX
      });

      // console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);

      if (
        this.state.posCurrentX3 <= this.travelLength &&
        this.state.posCurrentX3 >= 0
      ) {
        // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider3.current.style.left = `${this.state.posCurrentX3}px`;
        this.value3.current.innerHTML = Math.round(
          (this.range / this.travelLength) * this.state.posCurrentX3
        );
      }
    });
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.slider1.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown1);

    this.slider2.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown2);
    this.slider3.current.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmouseDown3);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  // componentWillUnmount() {
  //   document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onmousedown1);
  //   document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onmousedown2);
  //   document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onmousedown3);
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>Hello All</h3>
        <input type="text" name={this.state.name} onChange={this.onType} />
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="bar" id="bar" ref={this.bar}>
              <div
                className="slider"
                id="slider-1"
                ref={this.slider1}
                onMouseDown={this.onmouseDown1}
              ></div>
              <div
                className="slider"
                id="slider-2"
                ref={this.slider2}
                onMouseDown={this.onmouseDown2}
              ></div>
              <div
                className="slider"
                id="slider-3"
                ref={this.slider3}
                onMouseDown={this.onmouseDown3}
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="values">
            <div className="value" id="value-1">
              3
            </div>
            <div className="value" id="value-2">
              4
            </div>
            <div className="value" id="value-3">
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default RefsDemo;
```

Slider.css

```
.box {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.bar {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider-1 {
  background-color: #6cc639;
}

#slider-2 {
  background-color: #3e4cda;
}

#slider-3 {
  background-color: #d33f43;
}

.values {
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#value-1 {
  color: #6cc639;
}

#value-2 {
  color: #3e4cda;
}

#value-3 {
  color: #d33f43;
}
```

[image: Triple Pointer Slider]

The three pointers are stuck at same place and I am unable to record mouse movements while dragging the pointers one by one.

I have tried adding the listeners as below in Slider.js file.However it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to create 3 separate bars with left: 0. In above code, you have left:0 for all so you can see last one.

Comment: Hi @Madhuri , No I want 1 slider wth 3 thumbs all starting from 0 and can be dragged to different positions.

Comment: Please see the 1st image I have attached.